# Нейронная сеть на python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Не так давно изучаю нейронные сети, и вот столкнулся с ошибкой, помогите разобраться

```
import torch
import random
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine


wine = load_wine()
features =  13 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    wine.data[:, :features], 
    wine.target, 
    test_size=0.3, 
    shuffle=True)

X_train = torch.FloatTensor(X_train)
X_test = torch.FloatTensor(X_test)
y_train = torch.LongTensor(y_train)
y_test = torch.LongTensor(y_test)

class WineNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_input, n_hidden_neurons):
        super(WineNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(n_input, n_hidden_neurons)
        self.activ1 = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_neurons, n_hidden_neurons)
        self.activ2 = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden_neurons, 3)
        self.sm = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.activ1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.activ2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

    def inference(self, x):
        x = self.forward(x)
        x = self.sm(x)
        return x

n_input = 2 # choose number of input neurons
n_hidden = 5 # choose number of hidden neurons
wine_net = WineNet(n_input, n_hidden)

loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(wine_net.parameters(), lr=1.0e-3)

batch_size = 10 # choose different batch sizes

for epoch in range(10000):
    order = np.random.permutation(len(X_train))
    for start_index in range(0, len(X_train), batch_size):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        batch_indexes = order[start_index:start_index+batch_size]

        x_batch = X_train[batch_indexes]
        y_batch = y_train[batch_indexes]

        preds = wine_net.forward(x_batch) 

        loss_value = loss(preds, y_batch)
        loss_value.backward()

        optimizer.step()

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        test_preds = wine_net.forward(X_test)
        test_preds = test_preds.argmax(dim=1)
```

и вот лог ошибки

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-336191ace60b> in <module>()
     64         y_batch = y_train[batch_indexes]
     65 
---> 66         preds = wine_net.forward(x_batch)
     67 
     68         loss_value = loss(preds, y_batch)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1404     if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
   1405         # fused op is marginally faster
-> 1406         ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
   1407     else:
   1408         output = input.matmul(weight.t())

RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [10 x 13], m2: [2 x 5] at `/pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:961`
```

Answer (score 2):

инпут не той размерности что веса сети

```
wine.data.shape
features =  2
```

разобрался